# Проблема с кодировкой python powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Функция вывода списка запущенных приложений. Но не дружит с кириллицей. При попытке декода в `utf-8` выдаёт `invalid start byte`. А при `1251` или `ANSI` - "Џа®Ў«Ґ¬  б Є®¤Ёа®ўЄ®©".

```
cmd = 'powershell "gps | where {$_.MainWindowTitle } | ' \
      'select ProcessName, Description, MainWindowTitle, StartTime, ID | Format-List *'

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
for line in proc.stdout:
    if not line.isspace():
        a = (line.rstrip())
```

Comment: cp866 . . . . .

Comment: @andreymal оно. Спасибо. В ответ может оформите?

Comment: @type49 Да про это вопросов и ответов уже много должно быть, я на такой тоже как-то отвечал